# Cannot affect page-margin sizes in KOMA2 Letter

Tags: lyx, margins, koma-script

No matter, what values I set in the Document->Settings->Page Margins, the PDF is rendered with the (very large) margins anyway.

[image]

I'm not trying to save paper, but the lack of the remaining width causes the (7-word) Subject of the letter to run over my name in the fancy headers.

Comment: Fancy headers might be an issue, because KOMAscript classes don't work well with fancyhdr, as far as I remember... Maybe make your document as short as possible, export it to LaTeX from LyX and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem. An example letter using exactly your margin setting:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass scrlttr2
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{mwe}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2cm
\topmargin 2cm
\rightmargin 2cm
\bottommargin 1cm
\headheight 5mm
\headsep 2cm
\footskip 2mm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Name
Cabohah
\end_layout

\begin_layout SenderAddress
Somewhere
\end_layout

\begin_layout Address
You
\end_layout

\begin_layout Opening
Hello You,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
Blindtext[10]
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Closing
Bye
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

produces:

[image: changed margins]

A test letter after deactivating your settings and using the defaults:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass scrlttr2
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{mwe}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2cm
\topmargin 2cm
\rightmargin 2cm
\bottommargin 1cm
\headheight 5cm
\headsep 2cm
\footskip 2cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Name
Cabohah
\end_layout

\begin_layout SenderAddress
Somewhere
\end_layout

\begin_layout Address
You
\end_layout

\begin_layout Opening
Hello You,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
Blindtext[10]
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Closing
Bye
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

produces:

[image: default margins]

As you can see, the margins are different.

So there must be another reason for your problem. But without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4488/277964) it will be hard to find it.

Comment: Don't delete it, your answer is helpful. My first thought was, whether the LyX GUI as dispayed in the question would meet the requirements of KOMAscript. It seems that it does. Anything else would have surprised me, because when I used LyX many years ago, using KOMAscript classes worked very well!

Comment: You have centimeters in a few places, where I have millimeters.

Comment: @MikhailT.  Indeed, nevertheless it shows, that changing the margin settings in LyX *does* change the margins of the document. And it shows, how to show a minimal working example, when using LyX. (Nevertheless, I would always recommend questioners to show a minimal working TeX document instead of a minimal working LyX document, because here are a lot of TeX experts with only rudimentary LyX knowledge.)

Comment: Having raised the values a bit here and there, I was able to cause the margins to change. I suspect, the code has some "sanity checks", which replaces extreme values with defaults :(

Comment: @KeksDose OK, I keep it and even have changed it to use `mm` instead of `cm` for head height and foot skip as it has been shown in the question.

Comment: @MikhailT. I've now changed the values in my example so that they should now be really the same as in your question. As expected the result for the vertical margins (at top an bottom) is even better to see than before. The change of the horizontal margins (left and right) is the same as it was in my previous example. So unless you show a minimal working example, your problem is still not reproducible even with your original values.

Comment: @MikhailT. BTW: LyX uses [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to change the margins. So there aren't any “sanity checks”. Even if you'd use negative values, these would be used.

Comment: Khm, I kept trying different values -- including negative ones -- and pressing "Apply". I'd then press Ctrl-R to update the PDF rendition, but the new evince-window popping up would still have exactly the same margins as the older one :(

Comment: @MikhailT. I understood this already the first time you wrote it. However, my example reproducible shows that this is not a common or general problem. So please do also understand, that we need a minimal working example to reproduce your problem and hopefully also find the reason and a solution.